# Can't use WebAsset useStyle in index.php in Joomla! 5

Tags: joomla-5.x, web-asset-manager

I am working on a Joomla! 5 compatible theme and want to use the WebAssetManager function in combination with joomla.asset.json to register and include theme assets. I am bumping into an issue where the following happens:

This is my joomla.asset.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
  "name": "base",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "description": "This file contains details of the assets used by this Joomla 5 site template.",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "template.base.style",
      "description": "Template CSS",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "media/templates/site/base/template.css"
    }
  ]
}
```

*Note: the file in the declared uri exists*

In my index.php I call the getWebAssetManager function:

```
/** @var Joomla\CMS\WebAsset\WebAssetManager $wa */
$assetManager = $this->getWebAssetManager();
```

After that I call the useStyle function to use the stylesheet like this:

```
$assetManager->useStyle('template.base.style');
```

And of course in the head of the page I jdoc include the stylesheets, like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="styles" />
```

The result is that stylesheets used by extensions are loaded in the frontend, but template.css doesn't.

Then I changed the code in index.php to register and include the stylesheet this way. So I don't use the joomla.asset.json but directly register the file:

```
$assetManager->registerAndUseStyle(
    'template.base.style',
    'media/templates/site/base/css/template.css',
    [],
    [],
    []
);
```

The result: it works! The file is loaded in the frontend the way it is supposed to be.

Can somebody explain to me why my first approach is not working? Am I overlooking something or is this a known bug in J5 which I didn't notice in de issue tracker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your working PHP code, the actual path to the file is this:

```
media/templates/site/base/css/template.css
```

But in JSON you wrote this:

```
media/templates/site/base/template.css
```

Correct it and it should work. Furthermore, you can simplify it to just `template.css`, template media path should be prepended automatically. Default Cassiopeia template has this, for example:

```
{
  "name": "template.cassiopeia.ltr",
  "description": "The css file to be used when the site is left to right (LTR).",
  "type": "style",
  "uri": "template.min.css",
  "dependencies": [
    "fontawesome"
  ]
}
```

Which loads `media/templates/site/cassiopeia/css/template.min.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to zip & "install" the template the usual way, the asset.json file gets not reconized when added / pasted / moved in manually after installation of the extension. At least its the case for components where i had a similar issue. After you have done it once you are able to make changes to the asset.json which gets loaded - its just the first time you have to do a "re-"install